# How do i get the rowID of a list item in another activity class?

Tags: android

In my main activity I have a list view of database items, when i long press on an item in a list it opens into a new activity that allows you to edit the item clicked.

The problem I'm having is that i'm not quite sure how to get the information of the rowID/primary key to the other activity java class so that i can start manipulating in that class e.g. set the initial values as the current row information and then being able to apply an update to it.

Incase this is of use to helping you help me here is what i have to take me to my new activity

```
 dialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialogEdit,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    long id = idInDB;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, edit_expense.class);
                    startActivity(intent);



                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onClick send the row id using putExtra

```
intent.putExtra("rowid", rowid);
```

On second activity get the extra string in onCreate()

```
String rowid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("rowid");
```

Comment: thankyou, this was exactly the piece of knowledge i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `id` is the id you want to pass to the other activity, use Intent extras to pass it.
`intent.putExtra("key", id);`

and to get the value in the other activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
long id = intent.getLongExtra("key", -1);
```

Intent reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

Hope fully in your list row you have a `textView` that contains the **ID**.
So when you load the `listView`, every row will add its own unique ID in the textView. Now when you click/hold the any specific listItem, it will trigger the click event and will retrieve the ID into the String rowID. Now you can pass this ID using intent.

```
list.setOnLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String rowID =((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rowID)).getText().toString();
                Intent nextActivity = new Intent();
                nextActivity.putExtra("id",rowID);
                startActivity();
}
```